# How to edit <?php print $linked_site_logo; ?>

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I've inherited a very large Drupal site and need to edit the content in `$linked_site_logo` as below, but I have no idea where to find this file.

```
<div id="logo"><?php print $linked_site_logo; ?></div>
```

What is typically the file structure for a large-scale Drupal site and where should I begin looking to edit this? I haven't been able to locate the file.

Comment: Got to the root of your code base and search for its assignment `grep 'linked_site_logo' --include="*.php" -r .`

Comment: This is likely in a database, if there is a backend I would check there first and use the CMS engines proper way of configuring this.  Alternatively you can look at the source of the page to track down the actual logo files location in the file structure and replace it with another file using the same file name with FTP or SFTP.

Comment: turn on [theme debug mode](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overriding-themable-output/working-with-template-suggestions) and details about which file is being used to output the different parts of the page with be output as comments in the html

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an answer on a drupal community which might help you. https://www.drupal.org/project/corolla/issues/1472416 - which suggests the code maybe in the page.tpl.php file

However, your best bet might be to use your terminal or code editor to do a search across the code base for the line of code, as there could be multiple references to the logo being included.

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: thanks @barmar - will keep this in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably in your theme template files page.tpl.php or in include header file. Use theme debug mode, put this in your settings.php at the end of the file: 
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;

Than inspect element using your browser and see where elements come from.